# Xcode equivalent for Visual Studio environment variables

Tags: visual-studio, xcode, environment-variables

I use premake to build solutions for Visual Studio and Xcode. Does anybody knows the equivalent environment variables in Xcode for Visual Studio $(ConfigurationName) and $(SolutionName)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(SolutionName)` -> `$(PROJECT_NAME)`
`$(ConfigurationName)` -> `$(TARGET_NAME)`

See e.g. [here](http://codeendeavor.com/archives/626) how to retrieve a list of all enviroment variables:

> - make a new empty xcode cocoa project
> - add a new “run script build phase phase” to the app target
> - add this as the script: `env > ENV`
> - build the project.